# Почему echo выводит значение которое переопределенно после его выполнения?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть простенький скрипт регистрации/входа.
Вопрос почему мой echo $_SESSION['message'] срабатывает после того как он перезадаётся. Хотя у меня сначала идёт echo а потом переопределение. Но эхо каждый раз идёт с переопределённым значением, т.е. чтобы я туда не писал у меня всегда будет эхо того что я напишу после эхо. А если я не сделаю переопределения то оно будет выводить то что задано в auth.php. Изначально обозначение идёт в конце auth.php. Ума не приложу почему так происходит.

```
//Index.php:

<?php

session_start();
define("secure",true);

include("db.php");
include("auth.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Супер Страница!</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <?php


            echo $_SESSION['message'];
        $_SESSION['message'] = 1;

  include "$login";
  ?>

  <!-- Комментарий -->

 </body>
</html>

//auth.php:
    if (!defined("secure")){
http_response_code(404);
die;
};


    if ($_POST['password'] && $_POST['username']){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $check_user = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($check_user) > 0){
                $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                header("location:index.php");
                }
                    else 
                        echo "Неправильно введены данные!";
        }
    elseif ($_POST['password'])
            echo "Введите имя";
    elseif ($_POST['username'])
            echo "Введите пароль";  
    elseif ($_POST['submitlogin'])
            echo "Введите все данные!";


    if ($_POST['newpassword'] && $_POST['newusername']){
            $username = $_POST['newusername'];
            $password = $_POST['newpassword'];
            if (mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users1 VALUES (NULL,'$username','$password')")){
            $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            echo "Регистриация прошла успешно!";
            }
                else
                echo "Такой пользователь уже есть!";
        }
    elseif ($_POST['newpassword'])
            echo "Введите имя";
    elseif ($_POST['newusername'])
            echo "Введите пароль";
    elseif ($_POST['submitreg'])
            echo "Введите все данные!";


    $login = "login.php";
    if (isset($_GET['reg']))
        $login="reg.php";
    if ($_SESSION['logged'] == 1)
        $login = "logged.php";
    if ($_GET['logout'] && $_SESSION['logged'] == 1){
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Вы вышли!";
        header("Location:index.php");
        };
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION это своеобразный серверный cookie, который храниться пока сайт открыт. Когда ты переходишь со страницы на страницу, используется одна и та же сессия. И если переменная уже была объявлена раннее, тогда она будет показываться в месте, где у тебя  echo.

Comment: Всё верно. Только у меня переменная обьявляется вот сдесь:

if ($_GET['logout'] && $_SESSION['logged'] == 1){
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Вы вышли!";
        header("Location:index.php");
        };
    ?>

дальше грузится индекс и идёт 
echo $_SESSION['message'];
        $_SESSION['message'] = 1;

но echo высвечивает 1 а не "Вы вышли!";

Comment: я просто хочу удалить эту переменную после единократного отображения. но в итоге она сначала удаляется и в итоге ничего не показывает. хотя эхо стоит перед удалением

Comment: Чисто методом тыка нашел причину. Всё неработало потому что было над include-ом $login, Где выводилась простая форма html. Поставив код после инклюда всё заработало и вывев оба куска в отдельные <?php ?> то же всё заработало. Почему я так и не понял. Вот кусок кода который выводился в $login <?php
if (!defined("secure")){
http_response_code(404);
die;
};
?>
<form method = "POST">
Имя пользователя
<input type = "text" name="username">
Пароль
<input type = "text" name="password">
<input type = "submit" value="Вход" name="submitlogin">
</form>
<a href="index.php?reg">Регистрация</a>

Comment: и ещё нужем был die; в конце первого куска